# How do you reload a UIView?

Tags: xcode, ios4, uiview, nsnotificationcenter, reloaddata

I have a UINavigationController where the user can go back/fourth. When the user goes back, I want that UIView to reload. ( I am actually using an [OHGridView](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHGridView) ). On my `ViewWillDisappear`, I do something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadOHGridView" object:self];
}
```

So when they go back, it will send a NSNotification to the OHGridView to refresh it's data. It get's called, but it get's an error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewController reloadData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b9e9f0`

Here's how I set up my NSNotificationCenter (in my DetailViewController):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ReloadGridNotification:) name:@"ReloadOHGridView" object:nil];
}

- (void)ReloadGridNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{

    [database executeNonQuery:@"DELETE * FROM images"];
    [items removeAllObjects];

    [self reloadData];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Now you would think it would update, but I get that error... Please help!

Coulton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I wouldn't think that it would update. `reloadData` isn't the name of a documented method of UIViewController, and you don't seem to have implemented one yourself. I'm not familiar with OHGridView, but I perhaps *that's* the object to which you want to send the reloadData message.

So you can change the observer that you set up from `self` to your instance of OHGridView, or you can implement a method in your view controller called `reloadData` that in turn sends the appropriate reload message to your OHGridView.

Comment: Thanks! I created a IBOulet like this: `IBOutlet OHGridView *ohGridView;` and called the refresh like this: `[ohGridView reloadData]`... Just incase anyone else is having the same problem!